# Download image in mobile in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

I created a flutter web app that creates an image and generates the base64 data. so I used AnchorElement in the HTML package to download the image to the client, it works on mac and windows but when I want to be downloaded on mobile nothing happen at all.

any clue?

code:

```
Future<void> downloadImage(Uint8List data8) async {
    try {
      final base64data = base64Encode(data8);
      final a = html.AnchorElement(href: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,$base64data');
      a.download = 'image.jpg';

      a.click();
      a.remove();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In general mobile apps need rights to access certain resource, e.g. access the network.

Search for **entitlement** on iOS [like this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_network_client) and [manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting)  on Android.

You need to set these rights in the iOS or Android project. Without this rights, access gets simply denied.